# Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have problem with website slide. after clicking on inspect element in chrome i get massage

"Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function"  in file custom.js

here is file code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#slider').nivoSlider({pauseTime: 4500});   });
}
```

here is website address http://myisraeltoday.com using WordPress

Theme: http://wordpress.org/themes/effect

Help needed

Comment: How and where are `.nivoSlider()` and `.imgLiquid()` defined?

Comment: I would love to get a massage every time I inspect an element!

Answer (score 0):

That means that you're calling something as a function (or method), when in fact it doesn't exist. You're calling three functions:

- `jQuery`
- `jQuery(document).ready`
- `jQuery('#slider').nivoSlider`

The third of these is most likely the problem.

Comment: so any solution because same file work on other websites

Comment: Well, do you have the Nivo Slider plugin set up? (Did you follow its directions? Did you Google it?)

Answer (score 0):

try changing your code to this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#slider').nivoSlider({'pauseTime': 4500});
 });
```

**PS :** Note the `});` at the end not just the `$`